# Trouble with MPI Allgatherv function

Tags: c++, mpi

I have been struggling to try to parallel this function which calculates interactions between particles. I had an idea to use Allgatherv which should distribute my original buffer to all other processes. Then using "rank" make a loop in which each process will calculate its part.In this program, MPI is overwritten to show stats that's why I am calling it mpi->function. Unfortunately, when I run it I receive following error. Can somebody advice what is wrong?

[image: Error]

```
void calcInteraction() {
    totalInteraction = 0.0;
    int procs_number;
    int rank;
    int particle_amount = particles;

    mpi->MPI_Comm_size(MPI_COMM_WORLD,&procs_number);
    mpi->MPI_Comm_rank(MPI_COMM_WORLD,&rank);
    //long sendBuffer[particle_amount];
    //int *displs[procs_number];
    //long send_counts[procs_number+mod];
    int mod = (particle_amount%procs_number);
    int elements_per_process = particle_amount/procs_number;
    int *send_buffer = new int[particle_amount]; //data to send
    int *displs = new int[procs_number]; //displacement
    int *send_counts = new int[procs_number];

    if(rank == 0)
    {
        for(int i = 0; i < particle_amount; i++)
        {
            send_buffer[i] = i; // filling buffer with particles
        }
    }
    for (int i = 0; i < procs_number;i++)
    {
        send_counts[i] = elements_per_process; // filling buffer since it can't be empty
    }

    // calculating displacement
    displs[ 0 ] = 0;
    for ( int i = 1; i < procs_number; i++ )
        displs[ i ] = displs[ i - 1 ] + send_counts[ i - 1 ];
    int allData = displs[ procs_number - 1 ] + send_counts[ procs_number - 1 ];

    int * endBuffer = new int[allData];

    int start,end; // initializing indices

    cout<<"entering allgather"<<endl;
    mpi->MPI_Allgatherv(send_buffer,particle_amount,MPI_INT,endBuffer,send_counts,displs,MPI_INT,MPI_COMM_WORLD);
    //                   ^from      ^how many        ^send   ^receive  ^how many  ^displ ^send    ^communicator
    //                               to  send         type    buffer    receive           type
    start = rank*elements_per_process;
    cout<<"start = "<< start <<endl;
    if(rank == procs_number) //in case that particle_amount is not even
    {
        end = (rank+1)*elements_per_process + mod;
    }
    else
    {
        end = (rank+1)*elements_per_process;
    }

    cout<<"end = "<< end <<endl;
    cout << "calcInteraction" << endl;

        for (long idx = start; idx < end; idx++) {
            for (long idxB = start; idxB < end; idxB++) {
                if (idx != idxB) {
                    totalInteraction += physics->interaction(x[idx], y[idx], z[idx], age[idx], x[idxB], y[idxB],
                                                             z[idxB], age[idxB]);
                }
            }
        }



    cout << "calcInteraction - done" << endl;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You are not using `MPI_Allgatherv()` correctly.

> I had an idea to use Allgatherv which should distribute my original
>   buffer to all other processes.

The description suggests you need `MPI_Scatter[v]()` in order to slice your array from a given rank, and distributes the chunks to all the MPI tasks.
If all tasks should receive the full array, then `MPI_Bcast()` is what you need.

Anyway, let's assume you need an all gather.

First, you must ensure all tasks have the same `particles` value.

Second, since you gather the same amout of data from every MPI tasks, and store them in a contiguous location, you can simplify your code with `MPI_Allgather()`. If only the last task might have a bit less data, then you can use `MPI_Allgatherv()` (but this is not what your code is currently doing) or transmit some ghost data so you can use the simple (and probably more optimized) `MPI_Allgather()`.

Last but not least, you should send `elements_per_process` elements (and not `particle_amount`). That should be enough to get rid of the crash (e.g. `MPI_ERR_TRUNCATE`). But that being said, i am not sure that will achieve the result you need or expect.